# Is it dangerous to short circuit D1 on STM32F4 Discovery Kit?

Tags: stm32

I damaged D1 on my STM32F4 Discovery board. Afterwards, I removed D1 and shorted there. Now, it works. Can I use it or is it dangerous?

[image: tm32]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the schematic on page 27 of [the manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/70/fe/4a/3f/e7/e1/4f/7d/DM00039084.pdf/files/DM00039084.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00039084.pdf), D1’s function is to prevent the external 5V power input from back-feeding the +5V from the USB.

With this shorted out, you should not have both the USB and the external power connected at the same time.

If you want to replace it, use a Schottky diode. The original is rated for 10 volts, 3 amps. You can use one rated for that voltage or higher and, to be safe, at least 2 amps.

Comment: ... and since you were clumsy enough to blow the diode in the first place, it would be a VERY good idea to replace it so that you don't blow up your computer next.

Comment: Thank you. Is it okay the use this one then ? https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/SS39-D.PDF

Comment: Yes, that should work fine